# How to ensure cache doesnt become to full?

Tags: android, caching

I am working on a project that uses a lot of fetching of text from a website. and downloading 4 images once a week and overrwritting them to the same cache.

What i am worried about is the cache becoming to full of files storing bitmap data. It initially takes up about 1.45mb of cache and continues to grow the more the images are fetched.

So how can i ensure that each time the new images are downloaded the old ones are erased?

Or do i not need to worry about the clean-up of the application's cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the docs:

```
getCacheDir ()
```

Returns the absolute path to the application specific cache directory on the filesystem. These files will be ones that get deleted first when the device runs low on storage. There is no guarantee when these files will be deleted. **Note: you should not rely on the system deleting these files for you; you should always have a reasonable maximum, such as 1 MB, for the amount of space you consume with cache files, and prune those files when exceeding that space.**

its up to you, its a FileHandle you can create erase update move rename the files.
I can think of a filecheck like: if file004 exists, remove it, create new file

or if you prefer the softer way, only set the `deleteOnExit()` flag on files you dont need anymore.

edit: sure, there you go

```
File cachedir = getCacheDir();
for (File f : cachedir.listFiles()) {
    if(!f.getName().equals("newFiles")){
        f.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay Thanks for the response.. The only thing is..I only want to delete the previous cache files when the new cache files are downloaded. This is about every 4 days, which i set to fire with an Alarm. So how would i go about deleting all the prevous cache images when the new ones are fetched every 4 days?

Comment: Ok, in my 4-Day-Downloadservice i would first download the new files into a subdirectory of the cachedir called "new". Than i would delete everything inside the Cachedir Folder except the "new" folder, than i would move the new files from the new folder into the cachedir. Was that your question or did i understand you wrong?

Comment: Yeah..I like the idea. So in my service..I could i just erase everything in the cahce and then download the new images on all on the 4th day in the service?

Comment: but what if the download failes? this is the reason i would try to download first and if succeeded remove the old data.

Comment: Good point..So...If i download the images first..and then erase..How would i guarantee that the new fresh images will remain untouched?

Comment: My fear is the new downloaded images will be deleted along with the old ones as a result of me cleaning the cache.

Comment: you create a folder newFiles inside the cachedir and download the fresh files into this folder, when you wipe the cachefolder (with a for loop for example) you skip the whole newFiles folder, your fresh files will be saved.

Comment: Thanks..But kind of confused...SO i download the new images to a folder names new..Then delete a folder named new?

Comment: Note that there is a negation. If the file/folder is *not* named newfiles than delete it.

Comment: Okay but the thing is..So i download images this week into the newFiles folder...Then the next week, i erase everything except the newFiles folder..Then the old files will never get deleted like i want them too?

Comment: please read my 2nd comment carefully ;) after the erase you move the files from the new folder into the cachedir folder

Comment: Got it..But the code didnt suggest that.lol..Could you make it relevant

Comment: Or put the code to make sense of what you suggested. =) Then it will definitely be clear